# Is there a way to send private messages/e-mails to members directly through Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, email, private-messaging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

I'm just curious... is there a way to send private messages/e-mails to members directly through Stack Overflow?

Comment: I can see this being suggested, even if I don't, but I think this ought to be elsewhere, perhaps: http://meta.stackoverflow.com. If not, then maybe there is another, proper place?

Comment: It's been suggested and turned down: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user

Comment: You can join chat rooms in Stack Overflow I think, and you can create gallery chat rooms with users you choose.  more details here:  http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms

Comment: No there isn't.  I think this question has been asked on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Comment: If you come as far as meta, you might be interested in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60185/alternative-to-private-messaging-in-chat) (declined) feature request.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a reliable way.

If you are lucky, a member will have a link to their blog (or even their email address) on their profile page.

If you are truly desperate, you can try contacting the moderators (contact us link at the footer) and they might be able to help if convinced that there is enough weight to your need.

As for why this doesn't already exist - read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) meta discussion.

Comment: So its quite clear to me the majority of people want this feature implemented, but the powers that be dont wish to listen to their consituency and make it happen huh? Sounds a lil bit like our govt.

Comment: @WillingLearner: 67 upvotes don't constitute a majority.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in chat, you *can* delete posts (within a 2 minute window*). So you could create a public room for yourself and the other person, make sure they're there, post your address then delete the post as soon as they acknowledge.

<sup>* I *think* it's 2 minutes</sup>